Filtering list of dicts and add new key:value from the loop item to all dicts in list
I'm trying to prepare a list of dicts with all needed data received from JSON file. I already parsed the file and it looks good but I still need to:

Add new element to every dict in the list "package: item" where item is get from the with_items: "{{ packages_to_import  }}". This variable is a simple list with all files I need to process.

Is there any way to also filter this list (in the same task) and remove all dicts where on of the keys has null value? I can add condition do the next task but then there is a lot of skipped items and it makes the output less readable.


my task:
- name: "Read JSON files"
  set_fact: 
    json_content: "{{ json_content | 
                      default([]) + ((lookup('file', item) | 
                      from_json ).transferDetails | 
                      json_query('[].{name: transferObject.summary.name, id: transferObject.summary.id, path: transferObject.contentSourceLocation}') |
                      list }}"
  with_items: "{{ packages_to_import }}"

Current dict that I manged to create:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": "123456789",
            "name": "filename1",
            "path": null
        },
        {
            "id": "1234567",
            "name": "filename2",
            "path": "/folder1/folder2"
        },
        {
            "id": "1234567",
            "name": "filename3",
            "path": "folder1"
        }
}

I would like to achivie:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": "1234567",
            "name": "filename2",
            "path": "/folder1/folder2",
            "package: "/folder1/folder2/file2
        },
        {
            "id": "1234567",
            "name": "filename3",
            "path": "folder1",
            "package: "/folder1/file3
        }
}

EDIT:
the structre of packages_to_import is:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "/path_to_file1/file1.json",
        "/path_to_file1/file2.json",
        "/path_to_file1/file3.json"
    ]
}




Given the files for testing
shell> cat /tmp/ansible/file1.json 
transferDetails:
  transferObject:
    contentSourceLocation:
    summary:
      id: 123456789
      name: filename1

shell> cat /tmp/ansible/file2.json 
transferDetails:
  transferObject:
    contentSourceLocation: /folder1/folder2
    summary:
      id: 1234567
      name: filename2

shell> cat /tmp/ansible/file3.json 
transferDetails:
  transferObject:
    contentSourceLocation: folder1
    summary:
      id: 1234567
      name: filename

Declare the list
  packages_to_import:
    - /tmp/ansible/file1.json
    - /tmp/ansible/file2.json
    - /tmp/ansible/file3.json

Read the files
    - command: cat {{ item }}
      register: out
      loop: "{{ packages_to_import }}"

Declare the list
  json_content: "{{ out.results |
                    map(attribute='stdout') |
                    map('from_yaml') |
                    json_query(_query) }}"
  _query: '[].transferDetails[].{name: transferObject.summary.name,
                                 id: transferObject.summary.id,
                                 path: transferObject.contentSourceLocation}'

gives (as expected)
  json_content:
  - id: 123456789
    name: filename1
    path: null
  - id: 1234567
    name: filename2
    path: /folder1/folder2
  - id: 1234567
    name: filename3
    path: folder1

Q: "Add new element package: item to every dict in the list."
A: Use the filer community.general.dict_kv to create the list of new elements, zip the lists, and combine items
  json_conten2: "{{ packages_to_import |
                    map('community.general.dict_kv', 'package') |
                    zip(json_content) |
                    map('combine') }}"

gives
  json_conten2:
  - id: 123456789
    name: filename1
    package: /tmp/ansible/file1.json
    path: null
  - id: 1234567
    name: filename2
    package: /tmp/ansible/file2.json
    path: /folder1/folder2
  - id: 1234567
    name: filename3
    package: /tmp/ansible/file3.json
    path: folder1

Q: "Remove all dictionaries where a key has a null value."
A: Count the number of valid values and add a new element
    json_conten3: "{{ json_conten2 | json_query('[].*') | map('length') |
                      map('community.general.dict_kv', 'valid') |
                      zip(json_conten2) |
                      map('combine') }}"

gives
  json_conten3:
  - id: 123456789
    name: filename1
    package: /tmp/ansible/file1.json
    path: null
    valid: 3
  - id: 1234567
    name: filename2
    package: /tmp/ansible/file2.json
    path: /folder1/folder2
    valid: 4
  - id: 1234567
    name: filename3
    package: /tmp/ansible/file3.json
    path: folder1
    valid: 4

Now, the selection is trivial. For example,
  json_conten3 | selectattr('valid', 'eq', 4)



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    packages_to_import:
      - /tmp/ansible/file1.json
      - /tmp/ansible/file2.json
      - /tmp/ansible/file3.json

    json_content: "{{ out.results |
                      map(attribute='stdout') |
                      map('from_yaml') |
                      json_query(_query) }}"
    _query: '[].transferDetails[].{name: transferObject.summary.name,
                                   id: transferObject.summary.id,
                                   path: transferObject.contentSourceLocation}'

    json_conten2: "{{ packages_to_import |
                      map('community.general.dict_kv', 'package') |
                      zip(json_content) |
                      map('combine') }}"

    json_conten3: "{{ json_conten2 | json_query('[].*') | map('length') |
                      map('community.general.dict_kv', 'valid') |
                      zip(json_conten2) |
                      map('combine') }}"

  tasks:

    - command: cat {{ item }}
      register: out
      loop: "{{ packages_to_import }}"
    - debug:
        var: out

    - debug:
        var: json_content

    - debug:
        var: json_conten2

    - debug:
        var: json_conten3

    - debug:
        var: json_conten3 | selectattr('valid', 'eq', 4)



The problem is that the files contain more then 1 dict. There can be multiple same dicts (with different name, id and path). In this case I cannot use zip, that's why I asked how to do that using item from loop because only this way I'm sure that I will get correct filename.

I solve filtering using json_query so we can skip this one.

Sure we can. And you can delete the comments here and provide the filtering solution as part of your question.
